# Django get sum based on common key

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have following two models.

```
class TeacherInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    school_id = models.ForeignKey('admin_app.School')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

class AssignedSheetStatus(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey('admin_app.Levels')
    subject = models.ForeignKey('admin_app.Subject')
    set = models.ForeignKey('admin_app.Set')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('teacher.TeacherInfo')
    assigned_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    corrected_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now I want to join these two tables such that I have `name` from `TeacherInfo` and sum of `assigned_count` , `corrected_count`.

Normally for one teacher I would do :

```
AssignedSheetStatus.objects.filter(teacher__id=teacher_id).aggregate(Sum('assigned_count'), Sum('corrected_count'))
```

But here I want this for all of the teachers in `TeacherInfo`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so accept it , please.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way arround. Annotate over the TeacherInfo:

```
TeachInfo.objects.annotate(Sum('assignedshetsstatus__assigned_count'), Sum('assignedsheetstatus__corrected_count'))
```

Comment: Maybe better with `annotate` instead of `aggregate`?